# test cudnn installation ubuntu 20 failed

Tags: nvidia, gcc, cuda

Okay so I have installed cudnn and want to test and verify the installation, but I got the below error, no matter what I do, the problem won't be solved.

edit: I have removed gcc and tried installing a lower version, but again gcc 9.3.0 is installed.

I get this error after running `make clean && make`

```
rm -rf *o
rm -rf mnistCUDNN
Linking agains cublasLt = true
CUDA VERSION: 10020
TARGET ARCH: x86_64
HOST_ARCH: x86_64
TARGET OS: linux
SMS: 30 35 50 53 60 61 62 70 72 75
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include  -m64    -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -o fp16_dev.o -c fp16_dev.cu
In file included from /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime.h:83,
                 from <command-line>:
/usr/local/cuda/include/crt/host_config.h:138:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
  138 | #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!
      |  ^~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:238: fp16_dev.o] Error 1
```