# gcc build and compile error ubuntu 20.04

Tags: compiling, gcc, cuda

I've installed cudnn but couldn't verify the installation because of [this error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234777/test-cudnn-installation-ubuntu-20-failed): `#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!`
After searching I found out that I should install another version of gcc and make a symbolic link for that. So I'm following [this guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) But I'm getting this error:

```
/home/---/objdir/../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/../gcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h:54:47: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
make[3]: *** [/home/---/objdir/../gcc-4.6.2/libgcc/shared-object.mk:12: unwind-dw2.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/---/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:18509: all-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/---/objdir'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:23788: stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/---/objdir'
make: *** [Makefile:899: all] Error 2
```

So my questions here are:

1. Does `#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 8 are not supported!` have anything to do with ubuntu 20.04? I mean if I install a stable version the problem will be solved or not?
2. How to fix the gcc error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46380601/5113137) solved my problem.
The point is that do not pay attention to the exact version number, for example there is no gcc-8 in [the directory](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/), just use the exact number.
In my case cuda-10.2, I used gcc-8.